# Power Automate Can't Create Work Items in Azure DevOps(Shared Inbox)

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate, azure-boards

I am facing a very weird scenario as I did not realize it until now.

I am using power automate to create work items when an email is received in the inbox and save attachments in the SharePoint and update the links of these attachments in the existing work item. I created this workflow using my user and in the 'To' field of the email, also gave my email address for testing purposes. After various iterations, I was able to successfully build the sample flow.

Now, what I did not know is, this workflow can only work if I am providing my email address in the 'To' field as this workflow is owned by me. When I updated the workflow to provide a different email address and tested the flow, it failed and gave a timeout exception, It could not detect the trigger.

My problem is:

My real scenario is, we will be receiving email requests in the shared inbox and once we receive those emails, a corresponding work item should be created. In such a case, how can I use power-automate to create work items? Will I need to create this automated workflow on the shared inbox itself by obtaining the user credentials or there is any other alternate way to achieve it?

I saw there is a template available for creating work items with a shared inbox. Here is what it shows, when I try to use this flow.

[image: Error]

Thanks,

Bee

Comment: Hi benz,
Not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Comment: Hey @Vito Liu-MSFT, I am still awaiting permissions of the shared inbox to be shared with me, so that I can test the flow. I will keep you posted about the outcome.

Comment: Hi benz,
If have any achievements, please feel free to let me know

Comment: Hey @VitoLiu-MSFT , I got the access today, it turns out to be a distribution list. Now I am stuck, how can I use a distribution list and make power automate listen to it. One workaround, I did was, i had gotten myself added to the distribution list, but still the 'To' field says distribution list name, not my email address. Any ideas, how to proceed now?

Comment: Hi @benz,
Do you now want to create a workitem when the distribution list receives an email? I tried it, it seems cannot do it. If have any misunderstanding, can you re-describe more details about scenario?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, the problem is, I came to know its a distribution list. I added my self to the distribution list, and receive an email, I can give my email address in the 'To' field of power automate and it will work seamlessly. After adding myself into the distribution list, I do receive an email, but still, in the 'To' field, the address is of the distribution list. I don't know how to tackle it. My scenario is, when an email request with a particular subject comes addressed to the distribution list, it should create a work item in azure DevOps. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @benz, I have updated the answer, please check it. As the test result, it can create the work item when distribution list receives an email.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, just to clear the solution once more, I am registered as a user in the distribution list, which means that I will receive the email automatically when a distribution list receives the email. The flow will exist on my email account. In your solution, you are suggesting me to put registration list email address in the To or CC field. The flow will be created through my email. Will it still work? Thank you

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT any feedback?

Comment: Hi benz,
I just finished the test. I am registered as a user in the distribution list and create the flow via my account, it will create work item when the distribution list receives the email. In addition, I try to add another distribution list member as the owner of flow and update the flow connection. The flow still work. 
By the way, the work item creator seems still show the first user account.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT , I have a question, what's the difference between To and To or CC field. Can you explain the mechanics internally? I want to understand the logic of how it all works. From the surface of it, an email is registered in the distribution list to which I am only registered as a user, I don't have any admin rights over that distribution list, how its reading from it. Just some internal mechanics. BTW, i have tried and it works smoothly. Thank you so much for your help. I will accept the answer as well, just want to understand internal mechanics.

Comment: Hi benz,Glad to hear that your problem has been solved. You could accept it as an Answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.
For the latest question, To or CC field contain To, if we configure the distribution list in the To filed, It will not work if someone send email and CC the distribution list. This is my test result, I recommend that you can raise it to the [Power Automate Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Power-Automate/ct-p/MPACommunity), They will give you a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use your account to issue any Outlook REST API request or when you use any Outlook functionality in Microsoft Flow, you may receive the error message: REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox
To fix this issue, use one of the following options, as appropriate for your situation.

1. Migrate your mailbox account
2. Wait for your mailbox to update, or request a developer preview account
3. Upgrade your Office 365 plan

Please refer this link for more details: ["REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox" error for request to a mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498356/power-automate-cant-create-work-items-in-azure-devopsshared-inbox)

As a workaround

1. Use your account create the flow-> open the flow and edit the tab owners, then add the shared inbox as owner
2. Login Power Automate via the shared inbox-> click My flows and select Team flows->open the flow and edit it->click the button "..." and add new connection->enter the shared inbox email and password, then change the Original Mailbox Address to shared inbox.
3. Then it will create work item In the Azure DevOps when the shared inbox receives an email

**Update1**

The distribution list has email address
Steps:
Expand the flow When a new email arrives and enter the distribution list email to the field To or CC, then it will create a work item when the distribution list receives an email.

> when an email request with a particular subject

We can configure the field Subject Filter to do this.

[image]